# Ir de un fragment a otro al seleccionar un item de un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy trabajando con Tabs Fragments. Dentro del primer fragment recibo Data de Firebase y la muestro con un recyclerview, utilizo la clase ItemClickSupport para el método de onItemClicked.

Éste es mi código:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recycler).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v){

        Fragment fragment = new NegocioFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("data", "This data has sent to FragmentTwo");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Diste click en el número: "+recycler.getChildAdapterPosition(v), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

El problema aquí es que, al dar click, me carga el fragment nuevo sobre el ya creado, pero quiero ir de un fragment a otro.

Éste es mi activity_main.xml `

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

En mi tab_fragment_1.xml sólo tengo la recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lstCategorias"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

y éste es mi negocio_fragment.xml el cual recibirá data en un recyclerview

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Negocios"
    android:id="@+id/lblnegocio"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/lstNegocios"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

y en mi clase NegocioFragment sólo tengo el onCreateView por el momento

```
public class NegocioFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.negocio_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Eso es como debe ser, si usas `replace(...)`en la transacción. Revisa el uso de `add(...)`si quieres agregar un fragmento y no remplazar uno.

Comment: Entonces quieres con el `onItemClicked()...` cambiar el fragmento manejado por el ViewPager? Trata de explicar precisamente en que elemento de vista quieres cambiar el fragmento.

Comment: no entendí... tienes problemas con los tabs? o con los botones que estan dentro de los fragment?

Comment: El problema es que cuando selecciono un item del recyclerview, quiero que me abra el fragment Negocio, y el actual fragment no se muestre, porque así como está, muestra el fragment, pero sobre el actual

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres remplazar, en vez del view pager en el ActivityMain pon un FrameLayout donde vas cargando tus Fragmentos. 
Por lo tanto crea otro layout para el viewPager que cargaras en dicho FrameLayout, luego cargaras el otro fragmento en ese hueco. Digamos ese FrameLayout es un hueco donde quitaras y pondrás fragmentos.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="6dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="6dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/contenedorDeFragmentos"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

De esta forma el código del onClick sería el siguiente. Cambia R.id.activity_main por r.id.contenedorDeFragmentos

```
Fragment fragment = new NegocioFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("data", "This data has sent to FragmentTwo");
fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorDeFragmentos, fragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda alomejor no me he explicado bien.

Answer (score 0):

El método `replace`se usa tipicamente en `FrameLayout` cuando reemplazas un fragmento con otro. En tu caso deberías usar `add`:

```
    Fragment fragment = new NegocioFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("data", "This data has sent to FragmentTwo");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

Si eso no te resuelve el problema, comparte el xml de tu layout por favor.

Comment: Al utilizar el add no me muestra el fragmento sobre el viejo, ya puse los xml que utilizo